# combination issue : operator '==' and operator '-'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a weird error when I try to compile this piece of code.
I will explain my problem.
I defined a vector2D as following:

```
typedef struct LX_Vector2D
{
    float vx;
    float vy;

    LX_Vector2D& operator =(const LX_Vector2D v);  // Defined

} LX_Vector2D;
```

I also defined two operators on this vector:

```
bool operator ==(LX_Vector2D& u,LX_Vector2D& v); // Are u and v equal?
LX_Vector2D operator -(LX_Vector2D& u);          // Get the opposite vector
```

All of these overloaded operators was defined.
So I tested these operators in the following code:

```
LX_Vector2D u = {3.14,-2.56};
LX_Vector2D expected_vec = {-u.vx,-u.vy};

if(expected_vec == (-u))    // ERROR
    cout << "OK" << endl;
else
    cout << "NO" << endl;
```

When I compile this code, I have this error:
***no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘expected_vec == operator-((* & u))‘***

I have no problem with '=' and '==' because I defined and tested them before I implemented '-'.

But when I modify this code to get this:

```
u = -u;
if(expected_vec == u)    // OK
```

I have no error.
I do not understand that, because it seems these two pieces of code are semantically identical.

Here is the definition of *operator '-'*:

```
LX_Vector2D operator -(LX_Vector2D& u)
{
    return {-u.vx,-u.vy};
}
```

So my question is:
Why doesn't my compiler recognize *‘expected_vec == (-u)‘* as a call of *operator '=='* with *expected_vec* and *(-u)* as parameters?

Another question:
How can I have the possibility to use *if(expected_vec == (-u))* without any problem, if it is possible?

I use g++ 4.6.1.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the *complete* error output, because what you show us should not be all.

Comment: Could you please tell us who taught you to say `typedef struct` so that we can create a large quarantine zone around that person?

Comment: Not directly related to your question but your assignment opeator should take a const reference.  It is currently passed by value.  Also, I think your operator- should return a reference.

Comment: @AnonMail Actually, as seen by my and owacoder's answers, it's *extremely* related to the question. :)

Comment: @AnonMail - "`operator -()` should return a reference". To what? Returning a value is perfectly suited to that operator.

Comment: @owacoder I wasn't sure if unary operator- acts on itself (like ++a) or on a copy of itself (like a++).  I've never written a unary operator before.

Comment: @AnonMail, actually the `operator-` should NOT return a reference since the OPer likely does not want to negate the original instance, but a copy.

Comment: @KerrekSB I always used `typedef struct` and I never had any problem with that (o_O).

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz Thanks, After searching, I see that the canonical operator- returns a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the result from `operator-` when used as part of another expression is a *temporary* value, and that `operator==` takes non-constant references. A non-constant reference can't bind to a temporary value.

The simple solution? Make the `operator==` function take constant references:

```
bool operator ==(const LX_Vector2D& u, const LX_Vector2D& v)
//               ^^^^^                 ^^^^^
// Note the use of `const`
```

---

As a general recommendation, when declaring functions that will not modify their arguments, always pass the arguments as constant. It will avoid problems like this, and may also help the compiler with possible optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

Operator `-` returns a temporary object:

```
LX_Vector2D operator -(LX_Vector2D& u)
```

while your comparison operator accepts a non-`const` reference:

```
bool operator ==(LX_Vector2D& u,LX_Vector2D& v)
```

Temporary objects, like returned by the `-` operator, cannot be used as non-`const` references. It's not allowed because there is no purpose modifying an object that is about to go out of scope anyway, so the compiler makes sure you don't even attempt it.

As a general rule, you should make any function that does not modify its arguments take `const` references instead, especially comparison functions:

```
bool operator ==(const LX_Vector2D& u,const LX_Vector2D& v)
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the other answers, your assignment operator should also take a `const&` as in:

```
LX_Vector2D& operator =(const LX_Vector2D& v)
```

note the `&` after the parameter type.

As a general rule, and to avoid the construction of unnecessary copies of objects, parameters of complex types should almost always be `const &` if you are not planning on changing the parameter instance. Or if you are planning on changing the parameter instance, then simply as a reference, i.e., `&`.